# Variable hiding and "priority" in c

Tags: c, variables, scope

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char i='u';
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

prints 0,1,2,3 in new lines, since the character variable `i` declared outside the for loop is "hid". But, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char i='u';
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        int i=8;
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

print 8 '4' times on new lines as if the variable `i` initialized as 8 has **more priority** than the variable `i` (counter) going from 0 to 3 .

The `i` in the for initialization and the `i` in the for loop **are in the same block**, but one seems to have more priority than the other. Does such a priority really exist and if yes, is there a defined order of priority?

Comment: such priority is defined by [scoping rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope), that is if variable of the same name is declared in outer scope, the visibility of the outer scope variable ends at the point of declaration of the inner variable

Comment: *"The `i` in the for initialization and the `i` in the for loop are in the same block"*. That's not true. From the C standard: *"An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement."*

Answer (score 1):

What you're calling "priority" is actually referred to as **scope**.

Each variable and function has an enclosing scope in which the name is valid and in which it has a particular lifetime.  If a variable in one scope has the same name as a variable at a higher scope, the variable(s) at the outer scope(s) is masked and only the one in the innermost scope is visible.

In the case of a variable declared in the initialization section of a `for` loop, these variables have a scope that is visible in the other parts of the `for` as well as the loop body.  If the loop body is a compound statement, that starts *another* scope, and variables declared here will mask variables with the same name at higher scopes.

So in your second program you have three variables named `i`:

- The scope of the first `i` is the body of the `main` function.
- The scope of the second `i` is `for` statement.
- The scope of the third `i` is the body of the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Such priority is defined by [scoping rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope):

> The scope of any other identifier begins just after the end of its declarator and before the initializer, if any:
>
> ```
> int x = 2; // scope of the first 'x' begins
> {
>     int x[x]; // scope of the newly declared x begins after the declarator (x[x]).
>               // Within the declarator, the outer 'x' is still in scope.
>               // This declares a VLA array of 2 int.
> }
> unsigned char x = 32; // scope of the outer 'x' begins
> {
>     unsigned char x = x;
>             // scope of the inner 'x' begins before the initializer (= x)
>             // this does not initialize the inner 'x' with the value 32, 
>             // this initializes the inner 'x' with its own, indeterminate, value
> }
>  unsigned long factorial(unsigned long n)
> // declarator ends, 'factorial' is in scope from this point
> {
>    return n<2 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1); // recursive call
> }
> ```

Comment: You can make some really stupid code with this.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I think this must be a popular technique in code obfuscation contest